# UIImage imageNamed size

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiimage

New to Objective-C, Cocoa, and compiled languages in general so forgive my ignorance:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1-filter.jpg"];
NSLog(@"myImage.size=%@", myImage.size);
```

Results in
    Thread 1: Porgram received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Why? How do I get the size of a UIImage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size is a structure.

Use either `size.width, size.height` or `NSStringFromCGSize(myImage.size)` for `NSLog` output.

Answer (score 2):

This is a subtle, annoying-for-beginners error. (I actually just ran into this last week.)

When you use the format string `%@` in an NSLog, the argument must be some kind of Objective-C object. (Behind the scenes, when you do `NSLog(@"%@", foo)`, the system calls `[foo description]` to figure out what string to output. If the variable you pass to NSLog is not an Objective-C object, the system will try to send a message to something that isn’t an object and then throw this error.)

In this particular case, you’re going to be getting an integer, so replace `%@` with `%d` in your format string to make everything work okay.

Additionally, as Eugene mentioned, you want to be accessing a part of the `size` object. So try

```
NSLog(@"size.height=%d", myImage.size.height);
```

**Edit:** this should actually be `%f` instead of `%d`, and please read the comments on this answer.

Comment: NSLog(@"size.height=%d", myImage.size.height); %f actually, those are CGFloats

Comment: The members of `CGSize` are `CGFloat`s, not `NSInteger`s. The correct formatter is `%f` or `%g` (or `%e` if you really, really like scientific notation). And for getting the whole size, not just the width or height, it's correct and easier to use `NSStringFromCGSize` and, since that returns an object, `%@`.